# split a text file into arrays

Tags: java, arrays, file, split

I have a text file in this form:

```
ID
FName
LName
City
Age
;
22333;Giannis;Georgakopoulos;Patisiwn, Athens;42
22222;Maria;Nikolakopoulou;Kabalas 33, Aigaleo;34
84567;Konstantinos;Santorinaios;Karaiskaki 44, Patisia;29
```

I want to read the text and put the first elements *(ID,FName,LName,City,Age)* up to `;` into an array. After this I want to put the rest into another.
And finally I want to put them into one array in the form like this:

```
ID    FName   LName          City             Age
22333;Giannis;Georgakopoulos;Patisiwn, Athens;42
22222;Maria;Nikolakopoulou;Kabalas 33, Aigaleo;34
84567;Kostas;Santorinaios;Karaiskaki 44, Patisia;29
```

I have started with the following code but I can't finish it.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(".../testing"));
    String line = null;
    String[] pinakas=new String[6];

    int i=0;
    while (!(line=br.readLine()).equals(";")) {
         pinakas[i] = line;
         i++;

        System.out.println(line);
    }
    br.close();
}
```

Comment: Have you thought about creating [Objects](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html)?

Comment: [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236/1393766) You need to be more precise about problem you are facing. So what is wrong with your code? What is stopping you from finishing it?

Comment: have a look at this: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_string_split.htm

Comment: Hint: Use `Scanner`.

Comment: ---Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question? You need to be more precise about problem you are facing. So what is wrong with your code? What is stopping you from finishing it?  ----

My problem is that i can fill an array with the first elements( up to the "; ")
But i cant find a way to read the rest of the file (after the first " ;") and put every line from there in an new(or not) array so after to have the opportunity to match the two arrays ...   If you have another idea  for making this happen, i am open to hear this..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let me try to give you a little direction.

```
List<Person> list = new ArrayList<Person>();
String line;
try (
    // open an input stream
    InputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream("".../testing"");

    // read file as UTF-8
    InputStreamReader reader = new InputStreamReader(fileInputStream, Charset.forName("UTF-8"));

    // open a BufferedReader to read line-by-line
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(reader);
) {
    while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
        // split the `line` on ";"
        // [0] - ID    
        // [1] - FName   
        // [2] - LName          
        // [3] - City             
        // [4] - Age
        String[] objects = line.split(";");
        int ID = Integer.parseInt(objects[0]);
        String fName = objects[1];
        String lName = objects[2];
        String city = objects[3];
        int age = Integer.parseInt(objects[4]);
        list.add( new Person(ID, fName, lName, city, age) );
    }
}

System.out.println(list);
```

An idea about what a `Person` object can look like.

```
class Person {
    int ID;
    String fName;
    String lName;
    String city;
    int age;

    public Person(int ID, String fName, String lName, String city, int age) {
        this.ID = ID;
        this.fName = fName;
        this.lName = lName;
        this.city = city;
        this.age = age;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return ID + ";" + fName + ";" + lName + ";" + city ";" + age;
    }
}
```

The opened file is read in lin-by-line. It would be a good idea to create an object, called `Person` of something, that would have ID, FName, LName, City and Age as fields. Then you could create a new `List<Person>` entry for each line in the file.

Does that help?

Comment: Why are you reading it like UT-8? ....i have tried this with split " ; "  but i couldn't find a way to get this result i want ..How i can set that the IDs would be the numbers ( 22333 etc . ) and etc for the rest of them  ?

Comment: You need to use `;`, not ` ; ` (no spaces); UTF-8 because you don't seem to be needing anything greater than that.

Comment: @cseKostas Let me update this with something that actually *uses* OOP

Comment: @cseKostas Done! Check it out :)

Comment: omg ...thanks a lot man .. i find a way to do it with 2 while loops and 3 ArrayList ( one for titles, one for the rest of elements ... and one with both of them ... )  .. i am from the phone now and i can't upload the code but thanks a lot !!

Comment: @cseKostas I think doing an `ArrayList` of objects is much cleaner than doing multiple loops/arrays/arraylists because it manages to keep the essence of OOP, keeps your code clean, maintainable and reusable. Like here, we have just one `Arraylist` of `Person` objects and *everything just works*. Please go through it and make edits as you deem required; I think you will find it immensely beneficial in the long run. :)

Comment: I can see what you are talking about... I tried but i had an error in this line of    list.add( new Person(ID, fName, lName, city, age) );   which was that something(of the arguments )  couldn't set right ... i couldnt understand why this was happening ...

Answer (score 1):

```
String data = null;

try {

    BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(filename));
    while ((data = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
        String[] tempData = data.split("\t");
        for (int j = 0; j <= 4; j++) {
            dataFromFile[totalRecords][j] = (int) Float.parseFloat(tempData[j]);
        }
        totalRecords++;
    }
} catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
    System.out.println("file not found");
} catch (IOException ex) {
    System.out.println("error in opening file");
}
```

Here I am reading complete first row and splitting it by spaces. and storing the records in to 2by2 array. This might help you!

Comment: Firstly, thank you very much for your time. but i have an "exception"  point it out for this line " dataFromFile[totalRecords][j] = (int) Float.parseFloat(tempData[j]);  "    ...  ...the only change that i have done to your code is to set "int totalRecords = 0;  & int[][] dataFromFile = null; "  before the "for loop" . do you have any idea why  i have this problem?

Comment: maybe i am thinking that in a wrong way.. Do you have any proposals about accomplish that i want with another way ?

Comment: What is the problem which exception are you facing ? May I have stack trace? In the present code you are trying to convert Data to float might be that is problem . Try to change that .Please post the problem clearly.

Comment: the problem is that "totalRecords" and "dataFromFile "  cannot be resolved into a variable ....   Just remember that I want a java program that it will take  any txt file in the format that i gave and get back (output) an array that first row will have (id,fname,lname,adress,age --> each of them in a separate column)  and below these names put the elements i gave before like (12231,giannis, papadopoulos, karaiskaki 32, 45 etc )  ..... Sorry if i cant be more specific ..I am new in java coding....

Comment: dataFromFile[totalRecords][j]= tempData[j];   try to usethis line inside for loop. Here we are trying to read the first row , split it based on spaces and reading it in to 2 by 2 array dataFromFile[][] . Please declare and initialize this array.

Comment: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException  i get this when i put  dataFromFile[totalRecords][j]= tempData[j];

i declare and initialize this array before for loop like this --> >   
  String[][] dataFromFile = null;
  int totalRecords = 0;

Comment: String[][] dataFromFile = new String [x][5]; here x is the ( total number of records in the text file+1  ) declare this out of try block.

Comment: Now i get this  --->   Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 1

Comment: that means you are not properly assigning the size to array. try to find the value of x and assign it. the value of x is the number of rows in the text file.